# Double apps on Ubuntu Dock

Tags: ubuntu-dock

Last week I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. It seems when computer goes to sleep and re login, this happens:

[image: screenshot]

I used Tweaks & Dconf Editor to customize desktop.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on? 20.24 isn't a version that exists

Comment: Me bad lol using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS I noticed there are 2 dock overlaying each other. How do I remove one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have more than one "Dock" extension enabled, e.g., Dash to Dock and Ubuntu Dock.

Comment: Ok i have figured it out as I used Extentions to remove 2 dock. Thank you!